# EXTJS 7.X Modern Kit Button Disabled

Tags: extjs7

**I want to disabled an Export Button when the data not available in the grid.**

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to disable the export button when the grid has no data loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid should have a store set up that loads data?
You could listen on your store for data changes.

```
listeners: {
        datachanged: function(store, eOpts) {
            //localize your button
            let yourButtonInToolbar,  //Get Button (e.g. via ComponentQuery)
                boolean = store.getData().getCount() === 0;

            yourButtonInToolbar.setDisabled(boolean);
        }
    }
```

In this event the store should already have set the data if changes occured.
I did a boolean depending on the Output of the `getCount`method inside the result of the `getData` method on the store.

With this boolean I use the setDisabled method on the localized button in your toolbar.

I hope this helps.